# What is the difference between <class 'str'> and 'str'?

Tags: types

Every time I loop through a list of strings I get this result and I've never seen something like this before.

```
stringList = ['test','test1']
for i in stringList:
    print(type(i))
    break;
```

returns:

```
<class 'str'>
```

What is the difference between this and a regular string? Is there a way to convert one to another? Or are they meant to work the same way? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you're printing here is the `type` of i, rather than `i` itself.  Python has a class called `str` that represents strings.  When you create a string in python, you are creating an instance of this class. Please refer to this link regarding the str class: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str

And check this link for documentation around `type` https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type

Comment: I am afraid he is asking different thing. I too am facing the same problem. I want to convert navigablestring to str type to perform some operations. But I could only convert it to <class str> and not pure str. E.g. if you directing define a string variable in Python and check its type, you will get 'str' as its type and not <class str>. And they are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Every data type in python is an instance of a class.
In this case `type(i)` returns the class of `i` that is `str`.
If you also add this line before the break you can see that `i` is an instance of the str class:
`print(isinstance(i, str))`